# Testng - How to fail AfterClass method if a test method fails?

Tags: java, testng

I want the AfterClass code to not run if there is any failure before it. That is, if a test fails, then AfterClass should not run. How do I achieve that ?

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Testing {
    @BeforeClass
    public void b4class(){
        System.out.println("b4class");
    }

    @Test
    public void t1(){
        System.out.println("t1");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("BOOM");
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = false)
    public void afterClass(){
        System.out.println("afterClass");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: I _think_ you can just do `@AfterClass(dependsOnMethods={"t1"})`

Comment: A quick thought. According to jUnit framework conventions, every test class runs BeforeClass and AfterClass methods once irrespective of success and failures of test cases defined. The afterClass method should be used to free any resources held or delete any data created in beforeClass method, etc. I think it would make more sense to use After method in your class rather than AfterClass method.

Comment: @LDorado this is not JUnit

Comment: @SeanBright - Thanks. But, people might forget to add it to the dependsOnMethods. I wonder if there is a short and simple alternative which automatically fails afterclass.

Comment: @MasterJoe2 "@AfterClass(dependsOnMethods={"t1"})" will not work. You can't have dependencies between test methods and configuration methods. Please see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/_w5MlfYizrA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use TestNG [listeners](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) to override the default behavior. For example, a very simple listener which could do that

```
@Listeners({Testing.MethodInterceptor.class})
public class Testing {

    @BeforeClass
    public void b4class(){
        System.out.println("b4class");
    }

    @Test
    protected void t1(){
        System.out.println("t1");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("BOOM");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass(){
        System.out.println("afterClass");
    }

    public static class MethodInterceptor implements IInvokedMethodListener {

        int status = ITestResult.SUCCESS;

        @Override
        public void beforeInvocation(final IInvokedMethod method, final ITestResult testResult) {
            if (method.isConfigurationMethod()
                    && method.getTestMethod().getMethodName().equals("afterClass")
                    && ITestResult.FAILURE == status) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("BIG BOOM");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterInvocation(final IInvokedMethod method, final ITestResult testResult) {
            if (method.getTestMethod().getMethodName().equals("t1")) {
                status = testResult.getStatus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```